# Does there exist a purely topological proof of infinitude of primes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I know that there is [Fürstenberg's so called topological proof of infinitude of prime numbers](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2lIeUodPQAhVMNo8KHYGxALkQFggkMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFurstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes&usg=AFQjCNHMSuKLJgk21kfOTOXMneFw0sAbqw) but as I have observed that it is essentially, a non-topological proof using topological terminology. So I was wondering if there exists a purely topological proof of infinitude of primes.

Can someone give me a hint or if possible can someone mention some relevant literature regarding this subject?

Comment: The usual notion of prime number isn't "purely topological", so you can't expect to use only topological notions to prove the infinitude of primes.

Comment: @Watson: Probably you are right. But actually I wasn't aiming for only that. It could be the case that "prime numbers" are really special case of some mathematical object(s) whose infinitude can be proved by purely topological means.

Comment: I'd be more interested in asking whether Fürstenberg's topology on the integers has any actual deep consequences that can't easily be expressed using only basic combinatorics of arithmetic sequences. My guess would be no, but I don't know. The utility of the topology here in proving the infinitude of primes, as I understand it, is just the cute ability to go back and forth between unions of arithmetic sequences and their complements.

Comment: The link between topology and number theory is still quite undeveloped; there is a post here that says that prime numbers are related knots in knot theory. (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31250/prime-numbers-as-knots-alexander-polynomial) It will be amazing to find a relationship though.

Comment: While I understand what you mean by ‘purely topological’, your dismissive ‘so called’ is unwarranted: the proof *is* topological. The language in which an argument is expressed makes a real difference in how easy it is for a given person to find or to follow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what we understand by a "purely topological" proof. As Brian pointed out, a proof is "topological", if the language used is from topology - even if one could restate it without using topology (which obscures the proof, according to many people). I do not really have a new proof at hand, but at least a recent paper [On an exotic topology of the integers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0713) by Rezsö L. Lovas and  István Mezö. Here the topological aspect of Fürstenberg's proof is discussed further.